# What the relation between '\n' and '\r' in printf?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf ("Hello\r");
}
```

In gcc compiler when executing this code it doesn't print anything. If I add `\n` to that printf statement like

```
printf ("Hello\r\n");
```

it print `Hello` . Why it act like this ? What happening in the output buffer?

Comment: Note that for streams open in text mode, as `stdout` is by default, C stdio functions such as `printf` convert between newlines on the C side and whatever is the standard line terminator for the host environment on the external side.  As such, you should always use `\n` (alone) for a text line terminator inside your C code.  It's very unusual to explicitly print a carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: Think about a typewriter. That long lever on the left end of the carriage is the "carriage-return" which moves the carriage all the way back to the right so the keys strike the carriage at the beginning of the line. In computer world that is `'\r'`(aptly carrying over the same name) At the same time the carriage also rotated the roller back by 1 line feeding the paper up so typing began on the next line. This is `'\n'` (newline). So `'\r'` returns the cursor to the begging of the current line and `'\n'` moves it down by 1-line. (your typewriter features for the digital-age...)

Comment: Think about a papyrus scroll. \n is like turning the handle to bring the next line into view. \r is only needed when you are not using the natural boustrophedon method of alternating writing direction on each line.  Clear now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\r` is a carriage return, while the `\n` character is a line feed.

A **carriage return** moves the cursor back to the beginning of a line.  This terminology dates back to typewriters, where the carriage which holds the roller and paper is moved all the way to the right.  The result is that any subsequent characters are printed over any prior characters starting from the start of a line.

A **line feed** moves the cursor down one line.  This term also dates back to typewriters where the roller is turned to move down one line.

How these characters are interpreted can vary from one OS or terminal emulator to another.  What happened in your case is that "Hello" is printed, the `\r` character is printed which moves the cursor back to the start of the same line, then the program exited and the shell printed its prompt over "Hello".

If you were to print a string that is longer than your shell's prompt, then you'll see the additional characters.  For example, if I change the `printf` call to this:

```
printf ("Helloxxxxxxxxxxyyyyy111112222333344445555\r");
```

When I run your program I get this:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ ./x1
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ 1112222333344445555
```

In contrast, when you print `\n` the cursor moves to the next line *and* goes to the start of that line.

Comment: Re "*when you print `\n` the cursor moves to the next line and goes to the start of that line.*", Not on printers. As its name implies, Line Feed advances (feeds) the paper by one line without homing the head. That's why you send CR LF to printers instead of just LF.

Answer (score 0):

'\n': When encountered during printing, it instructs the system to move to the next line, starting printing from the beginning of that line.

'\r': When encountered during printing, it instructs the system to return to the beginning of the current line without moving to the next line. This could be useful for overwriting or replacing text within the same line.